# SQL Server 2008 R2 intellisense not working

Tags: sql-server

Just started a new job and everything was already installed on my machine.
It's not exactly a friendly bunch. (early days)

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and I see I have Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

I don't have any intellisense in SQL Server Management Studio.

Googled and found hundreds of hits!!!

Ultimately I have found this link:

http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2507770&kbln=en-us#step1

The problem is I have so many hotfixes to choose from and I don't know which one
Do you know?

[image]

thanks a lot

Comment: Intellisense is not provided by SQL Server. It's provided by SQL Server Management Studio, which retrieves metadata about the database and offers suggestions for you. Do you have permission to read the database structure?

Comment: What version of the database are you connecting to? If you have SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2, but you're connecting to a SQL Server 2005 database - there's no intellisense support there!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all - intellisense in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and newer only works against databases that are also 2008 or newer - it will not work against a 2005 database.

Next - have you made sure intellisense is enabled in SSMS ?

[image]

Then - if it is enabled - sometimes it helps to refresh the local cache:

[image]

Comment: Marc,Done all that still not working.I am using all sql server 2008 connecting to a sql server 2008 database.still not working

Comment: Its a bug that occurs when you install SP1 of Visual Studio 2010.  Its not user error.

Comment: For SQL Server 2008, check this link https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/31/sql-server-2008-intellisense-does-not-work-enable-intellisense/

Answer (score 4):

Late answer but can be useful to other readers:

If you installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and you’re using SQL Server 2008 R2, it is likely that your IntelliSense may stop working. There is a fix for this and it was released in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1.

For more information please read this KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2531482

According this article http://www.sqlshack.com/using-and-troubleshooting-sql-server-intellisense-sql-server-2012-higher/, here are some of the common reasons why IntelliSense isn’t working:

1. Firstly check if IntelliSense is enabled as explained earlier in the article. Also ensure that the Statement Completions settings are correct.
2. Ensure that there is no syntax error anywhere on the page before your cursor, resolving the code error should re-activate IntelliSense.
3. IntelliSense does not work inside comments, uncomment the section to be able to get the suggestions.
4. IntelliSense does not work inside a quotes. Be sure to place your cursor outside of any quotes.
5. Ensure that you are connected to a SQL Server Instance or a database project.
6. IntelliSense is only supported on SQL Server 2008 and higher.
7. IntelliSense does not work for encrypted objects.
8. Not all syntax is supported.
9. Are you running in SQLCMD mode? Unfortunately IntelliSense is not supported in command mode. Return to regular mode to get IntelliSense.
10. IntelliSense is currently not supported for SQL Azure

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and realized that is nothing about VS 2010 or whatever app.

All you have to do to enable IntelliSense on SQL 2008 is:

1) Run Windows Update and install 2 updates about SQL Server 2008 (SP1 and SP3);
Link - http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=SQL%20Server

2) Restart and make sure Intellisense is enable on SQL Server: Tools>Options>Text Editor>Transact-SQL>IntelliSense

3) Refresh Local Cache by pressing Ctrl + Shift + R

4) Done.

Answer (score 2):

Also if you have **Query | SQLCMD** turned On it will stop IntelliSense from working, even though you have it set up in all the places mentioned above and you are on the latest patch.

Answer (score 1):

Though you're having SQL Server 2008 R2 IDE but if you're connected with SQL Server 2005, intellisense won't work.

Please check out [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/31/sql-server-2008-intellisense-does-not-work-enable-intellisense/) link, it might help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, one of the answers on this post, [Why is SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Intellisense not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552458/why-is-sql-server-2008-management-studio-intellisense-not-working), suggests that the second from the bottom would be the one you want:

SQLServer2008R2_RTM_CU7_2507770_10_50_1777_x64

However, that is just the hotfix that this was released in, there are more current cumulative updates. See the list here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981356

Answer (score -1):

Please re-install sql or Search on google Download "SQLServer2008R2-KB2507770-x86.exe" and Run 100% Work For sql sever R2 2008