# SQL Server Intellisense not working on *some* servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, intellisense

Intellisense works... On *some* of the servers. It's the same Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2008) I'm using to manage the servers but Intellisense doesn't work on one of the newer servers (not sure if other servers have the same issue, as of now I've only encountered this problem on one of the servers).

I checked all the settings etc, but as I said - it does work on *some* of the servers in SQL 2008 Server Management Studio so it seems like it's limited to this one specific server.

(I wasn't sure if this belonged here. If this post is in the wrong place please move it)

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343769/sql-server-2008-r2-intellisense-not-working) covers making sure it's enabled, which it sounds like it is (I'm linking it just in case).  There also seems to be an installation issue with 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 (also mentioned in that link) sometimes, and [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/intellisense-not-working-but-it-is-enabled) covers that.  We had the same issue on one of 2008 servers, and post an update, it finally worked (solution 2).

Comment: It's not that Intellisense isn't working, it's that it's not working on *some* servers.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from some very common reasons (which don't apply here, as you say it's not working only for some servers) listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks1ka3t6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

... did you happen to instal VS2010 lately? There's a bug that makes IntelliSense stop workingŁ
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531482

Also try to refresh IntelliSense cache after you connect to new server (SSMS): Edit>IntelliSense>RefreshLocalCache

Comment: Well, yes about a month ago. But I'm not the only user with the same problem so I doubt it's that. Worth looking into though.