# Query window popup help how do i add it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Hi guys i need help with something really trivial about the query window in SQL 2008.
When I write a command and/or declare a variable I want the pop up help like the one in VS2010
to appear like when you write string you just need to type s and scroll down in VS.

I hope I was clear if I was not then please point it out and I'll try to re-write my question
sens I don't know what this help pop up is called I don't really know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is IntelliSense not working? 3 possible reasons:

1 The object is not in the local IntelliSense cache, since it was created recently.  You can fix this easily by going to Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache, or CTRL+SHIFT+R.

2 The query window is connected to a downlevel server (e.g. SQL Server 2005), where IntelliSense does not function

3 Maybe you need to install SQL 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552458/why-is-sql-server-2008-management-studio-intellisense-not-working)

Comment: Thank you so much now it works!
And i have finely learned what it's called :)