# SQL server not starting automatically and intellisense issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed sql server 2008 R2 express on my machine and It is set to Automatic start in control panel services. But when I restart my computer, I have to manually restart it. Please

also, Intellisense is not available for me in SQL server management studio. I read somewhere that If I need to install some patch. Can you please send me link for the patch?

suggest me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest service pack. This will probably fix your intellisence problem and maybe your Startup problem too.

[SQL 2008 R2 Service Pack 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552458/why-is-sql-server-2008-management-studio-intellisense-not-working)