# SQL Server 2008 RC2 Intellisense not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, intellisense

I have tried everythig. I checked if it is enabled, I installed the hotfix (I already had it), and I just did a repair. I still don't have any intellisence.

What else can I check? This is driving me crazy!!

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, that one is what I have.

Comment: i had this problem too , i installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and after Visual Studio 2010 , and intellisence crashed , my solution : uninstall - install first VS and after SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Check the following reasons why it might not work:

1 The query window is connected to a downlevel server (e.g. SQL Server 2005), where IntelliSense does not function

2 Maybe you need to install SQL 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552458/why-is-sql-server-2008-management-studio-intellisense-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I did a full reinstall (not repair) and it is working now. It was probably a corrupted install. Hope this saves someone time!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try and refresh the local IntelliSense cache in the Edit->IntelliSense menu.

Comment: I did this too, I explained in my answer how I got it to work.