# xp_cmdshell failure in sql server 2008 r2 express edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, administrator, database-administration

I am getting issue with xp_cmdshell procedure . I am running below command from ssms connected to sql server 2008 r2 express edition .

**exec xp_cmdshell 'echo abc'**

it result in null and message 1 row effected. it does not return abc as result. 
xp_cmdshell is enabled as from above result which is not showing any error .

Please look in to the issue .

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 RC2 Intellisense not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331150/sql-server-2008-rc2-intellisense-not-working)

Comment: I did`t find the solution on the link above ..

Comment: Did  you install the latest service pack?

Comment: which service pack do I need to install ..??

Comment: Maybe you need to install SQL 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 according to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552458/why-is-sql-server-2008-management-studio-intellisense-not-working)

Comment: ON select @@version : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64) 
  Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 
Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: ) , I found above. now can u suggest wat service pack do I need?

Comment: I have got windows edition : Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard . Is there any relationship of sql server intellisense to it ???

Comment: Yes. As I said: Install the latest service pack for your SQL Engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried everything then try to close and open the SSMS again and also you can try refresh the cache (Edit-->Intellisense-->Refresh Local cache (Ctrl+Shift+R))