# Unable to use Intellisense on SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Management Studio. My intellisense is not working, it is enabled when I right click but still not able to use.

Does anyone know about why this happens? And why am I not able to use it?

Comment: Difficult to determine the exact problem from your question, but try `CTRL+SHIFT+R` to refresh the intellisense cache

Comment: yeah that i know but when i type DBname with dot it should show intellisense but not showing.

Comment: @VikrantMore I suggest you to use third party software  http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/ free edition has Intellisense 

Why it doesn't work - If you've Visual studio install it may create problem explained here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552458/why-is-sql-server-2008-management-studio-intellisense-not-working

Comment: Just as a suggestion - please make sure that you're connecting to SQL Server 2008. SQL Server 2005 doesn't support intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some problem of missing dll files. Try updating your sql server and restart your machine. If there is still such problem than you have to reinstall it. That will be the last option.