# How Can Make sql server 2008 auto complete?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have SQL Server 2008 Management Studio's i need to be auto-complete while typing a query?
as 
when i write the letter such Cr .. Make Me  suggestion to Choose from All 
Reserved words AS Create .

Comment: It's called intellisense. Take a look here. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/31/sql-server-2008-intellisense-does-not-work-enable-intellisense/

Comment: Also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552458/why-is-sql-server-2008-management-studio-intellisense-not-working

Comment: yes intellisense .the article in blog i know it and do it . but not  make suggestion to Choose from Reserved words-that's i need- as when write cr.. suggest to me Create world

Comment: Why would you want to prevent keywords from showing up in intellisense? The point of intellisense is to make writing code easier. Keywords are a major part of queries...hence the name keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give Red Gate's [SQLPrompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) a try.  It isn't free but there's a free trial you can install to see if you like it.

Comment: no option in sql server 2008 allow us to make it auto-complete ?

Comment: Odd, try restarting SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

[ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx#) will do intellisense for your objects as well as SQL keywords, statements and identifiers. And it's free.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tools - 
  Options - 
   Text Editor - 
     Transact SQL - 
       General - 
         Auto List Members - Check - OK
Tools - 
  Options - 
    Text Editor - 
      Transact SQL - 
        IntelliSence - 
           Enable IntelliSense - Check - OK
```

Comment: do this but Reserved words not Active such as create when write Cr.. not suggest the reserved world Create.